# VBA - Run Time Error 9: Copy and paste

Tags: vba, excel

I recently learned about vba.

I've make a form with some fields, this fields function are

1. sheetname
2. range copy
3. range paste

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim barisawal As String
    Dim sampaiawal As String
    Dim tujuanawal As String
    Dim tujuanakhir As String


    barisawal = bariske.Text
    barisakhir = TextBox2.Text
    tujuanawal = TextBox3.Text
    tujuanakhir = TextBox4.Text
    sheetawals = sheetawal.Text
    sheetakhirs = sheettujuan.Text

    Worksheets("sheetawals").Range("barisawal:barisakhir").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheetakhirs").Range("tujuanawal:tujuanakhir").Paste

End Sub
```

When I click my submit button `CommandButton1`, I get a runtime error #9 "Subscript out of range".

Here what I want to do: the user will fill the form with worksheet name, range and worksheet destination for paste.

Comment: The first thing is that your variables `sheetawals`, `sheetakhirs`, `barisawal`, etc are already defined as strings, so you don't need quotes (`"`) around them.

Comment: after i remove " "  from -> Worksheets(sheetawals).Range(barisawal:barisakhir).Copy  the error is change

Comment: The next issue then comes with the `Range(...)` statement. The answers given show how to resolve this.

Comment: Thank you, now my script work. Oh yeah i add `Worksheets(sheetakhirs).Range(strRangePaste).Paste` to ` Worksheets(sheetakhirs).Range(strRangePaste).PasteSpecial`

Comment: I generally always use `.PasteSpecial paste:=xlvalues` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *subscript out of range* error happens on this line:

```
Worksheets("sheetawals").Range("barisawal:barisakhir").Copy
```

The `"sheetawals"` is understood by VBA as a literal string, so it's trying to find a sheet named `sheetawals` in the active workbook. When it doesn't find it, it blows up with runtime error 9 / subscript out of range.

As [@tospig correctly hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080405/vba-run-time-error-9-copy-and-paste#comment44539608_28080405), you mean to use the variables you've defined, not string literals - by removing the double quotes you'll fix your problem *if the specified sheet names exist in the active workbook*. Same for `Range` - you need to concatenate the strings using the string concatenation operator `&`, like this:

```
Worksheets(sheetawals).Range(barisawal & ":" & barisakhir).Copy
```

Same for the next line of code.

Now, you'll need to add some error-handling to prevent a runtime error when the user-provided values aren't legal. That's done with an `On Error` statement. Make that the first executable line of code in your procedure:

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
```

And then just before `End Sub`, add something like this:

```
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Invalid selection! Please try again."
```

Comment: @Boby thanks for the checkmark, don't forget to upvote tospig's answer as well, his comments and answer are good and useful - the best "thank you" you can give on Stack Exchange / Stack Oveflow, remains an upvote :)

Comment: Can i ask another question ? barisawal and tujuanawal values are from input form. How to prevent if the user submit wrong value ? for example , that form should be field with `b3` or `b4` what if the user only insert `b`

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested this code but this is how you should format the `strings` and `Range`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim barisawal As String
Dim sampaiawal As String
Dim tujuanawal As String
Dim tujuanakhir As String
Dim strRangeCopy as string
Dim strRangePaste as string

barisawal = bariske.Text
barisakhir = TextBox2.Text
tujuanawal = TextBox3.Text
tujuanakhir = TextBox4.Text
sheetawals = sheetawal.Text
sheetakhirs = sheettujuan.Text

strRangeCopy = barisawal & ":" & barisakhir
strRangePaste = tujuanawal & ":" & tujuanakhir

Worksheets(sheetawals).Range(strRangeCopy).Copy
Worksheets(Sheetakhirs).Range(strRangePaste).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

To use the `worksheet(...).Range(...)` you need to have a `string` representing the range you will be using. This is typically formatted like `Range("A1")`, or `Range("A1:A4")`